# Ingore flyway for multiple datasources

Tags: java, spring, datasource, liquibase, flyway

So I have two Springboot applications that are independant. Both are using distinct mariadb databases with distince schemas names.

To make it simple:

[image: scheme]

For some reason, my app1 has to be able to access db2 data. Ive been able to add a second datasource in my app1, however, due to differences between flyway and liquibase, it fails to start.

How can i do so that my flyway configuration is ignored for datasource 2 (db2). App1 should just access data (read/write whatever) but the whole database structure is handled by App2.

Comment: If you could provide some technical information such as the configuration/setup of these components it would help a lot in diagnosing the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Ingore Flyway? I loved him opposite Marty Feldman in Young Frankenstein.